# Unable to get HTML panel layout in Grafana working

Tags: html, css, grafana, inline

I'm using Grafana as a dashboard tool. In Grafana you cou can insert multiple panels such as, graphs, regular values, text, etc.

Problem:

I'm inserting a text panel that recognizes HTML:

[Edit section for text panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPDf6.png)

The code I'm using in this panel:

```
<h1 style="color: rgb(0, 131, 173); text-align: center; font-weight: 500; line-height: 2; font-size: 25px; margin-top: 5%;">GENERATOR</h1>
<img src="/public/img/AuxEngineIcon.svg" width="50%" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;"/>
```

However with this code the panel looks like this:

[Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZUC9.png)

The panel has added it's own scrollbar aswell.

What I'm to achieve is something like this:

[Achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlhLG.png)

Please note I cannot use a CSS file, online **INLINE CSS**

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance!